# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Column does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-polymorphic

I have a model class that inherits from two abstract models:

```
# vehicles app

class Car(
    PolymorphicModel,
    BaseSyncModel,
):
    """Car parent model."""

    id: models.UUIDField = models.UUIDField(  # noqa: A003
        primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4
    )
    store: models.ForeignKey = models.ForeignKey(
        CarStores, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    price: models.IntegerField = models.IntegerField()

    year: models.IntegerField = models.IntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1900), MaxValueValidator(2021)],
    )
    brand = models.TextField("Car's brand")
```

It inherits from the [PolymorphicModel](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and from a class to make sync, it is like that:

```
class BaseSyncModel(models.Model):
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

My problem is, when I pushed it to GitHub, the CI raised the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "updated_at" of relation "vehicles_car" does not exist
```

I think it is related to the multiple inheritances because the other classes that don't inherit from PolymorphicModel didn't raise the same error.

I have no idea how to proceed with that.

**EDIT - adding the migrations file**

I've done the migrations

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.24 on 2021-07-25 12:53

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

   dependencies = [
       ('vehicles', '0010_vehicles_context'),
   ]

   operations = [
       migrations.AddField(
           model_name='motorcycles',
           name='updated_at',
           field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
       ),
       migrations.AddField(
           model_name='car',
           name='updated_at',
           field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True),
       ),
   ]
```

**EDIT 2 - Polymorphic model**

[Here is the link to the polymorphic model on github](https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic/blob/b4efb59cd5d6b1ce3e10fdb5c495fbe239d91ad7/polymorphic/models.py)

**EDIT 3 - There is no relation with the polymorphic model**

I've removed the Inheritance from the Car model and let it only on the motorcycle model and it raised the same error, but for the motorcycle model:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "updated_at" of relation "vehicles_motorcycles" does not exist
```

Comment: Did you make migrations and migrate?

Comment: Can you show the PolymorphicModel?

Comment: @bdbd yes I've done the migrations, I'll edit the question and add the migrations file

Comment: @Francisco I've added the link to the polymorphic model on GitHub, because it's too large to put it here